# How to Auto search 2 PDF files for differences in character or words

Tags: pdf, comparison, character, difference, text-search

I'm searching for a program that can search for difference in text in two seperate pdf's. one pdf is of a scanned book and the other pdf is an OCR output of the same scanned pdf.  There are missing characters that I need to find, does anybody know how to go about this?

Comment: Are you attempting to write such as program, or find such as program?

Comment: I'm hoping to find such a program Jake.

Comment: Have you tried Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: Yes I did, Acrobat has the option to compare documents and suggests if there were changes made and updates to the two documents, but does not do a word count or compare the words or characters to see if are differences.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.textdiff.com, copy the file's text into the website and it will compare the 2?